Не отображаются картинки в PyQT + Pyinstaller
При попытке собрать exe файл python, в скомпилированной программе не видно иконок. Как бы я не пытался, у меня не получается сделать так, чтобы они появились. Вот сама проблема:
main.spec:
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-


a = Analysis(
    ['main.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[(r'C:\Users\PfeyferNY\Desktop\converter-yaml-to-json\images\gnivc2.png', 'images')],
    hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    noarchive=False,
    optimize=0,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    a.binaries,
    a.datas,
    [],
    name='main',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    runtime_tmpdir=None,
    console=False,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
    icon=['C:\\Users\\PfeyferNY\\Desktop\\converter-yaml-to-json\\images\\iconlogo3.ico'],
)

main.py:
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets    
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor, QIcon 
from PyQt5.uic import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import sys
import os
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
from ruamel.yaml.constructor import SafeConstructor
import json

import yaml

import psycopg2
from psycopg2 import Error





from py_windows.mainNew import Ui_MainWindow
from py_windows.informationsNew import Ui_MainWindow2

class Main_Screen(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main_Screen, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

class Informations_Screen(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow2):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Informations_Screen, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()


        self.fname = ""
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        #Начало класса Main_Screen
        self.main_screen = Main_Screen()
        # self.main_screen.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.add_file)
        # self.main_screen.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.save_file)
        # self.main_screen.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.gotoInformationScreen)

        self.main_screen.addFile.clicked.connect(self.add_file)
        self.main_screen.convert.clicked.connect(self.save_file)
        self.main_screen.info.clicked.connect(self.gotoInformationScreen)
        self.main_screen.add.clicked.connect(self.add_in_database)
        #Конец класса Main_Screen


        #Начало класса Informations_Screen
        self.informations_screen = Informations_Screen()
        self.informations_screen.back.clicked.connect(self.gotomain)
        #Конец класса Informations_Screen




        self.stack = QStackedWidget() # QStackedWidget видно сразу несколько виджетов
        self.stack.addWidget(self.main_screen) # 0 self.stack.setCurrentIndex(0)
        self.stack.addWidget(self.informations_screen) # 1 self.stack.setCurrentIndex(0)


        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(0)
        self.nameProgramm(self.stack.currentIndex())



        self.gotomain()

        hbox = QHBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        hbox.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0) #вроде можно без этого ????????????????????????????????????
        hbox.addWidget(self.stack)


    def nameProgramm(self, w=0):
        # self.setWindowTitle('Конвертер YML to JSON')
        # self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\converterGUI\\images\\gnvclogo.png'))
        self.setWindowTitle('Конвертер YML to JSON')
        base_path = getattr(sys, '_MEIPASS', os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
        icon_path = os.path.join(base_path, 'images', 'iconlogo3.png')
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon(icon_path))




    def gotomain(self):
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(0)
        self.nameProgramm(self.stack.currentIndex())
        #self.setFixedSize(421, 516)


    def gotoInformationScreen(self):
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(1)
        self.nameProgramm(self.stack.currentIndex())
        #self.setFixedSize(421, 516)




    def add_file(self):
        self.fname, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,"Open file", ".", "YAML Files (*.yml)")

        if self.fname:
            base_name = os.path.basename(self.fname) #Только для верхнего поля
            self.main_screen.lineEdit_3.setText(base_name)

    def add_file_json(self):
        self.fname, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open file", ".", "JSON Files (*.json)")

        if self.fname:
            base_name = os.path.basename(self.fname) #Только для верхнего поля
            self.main_screen.lineEdit_3.setText(base_name)

    def save_file(self):
        if self.fname:
            try:
                # Предполагается, что SplitFileByDuplicates может вызывать исключения
                SplitFileByDuplicates(self.fname)
                self.main_screen.lineEdit_3.setText("Конвертация завершена!")
                self.main_screen.lineEdit_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(66, 71, 90);"
                                                        "color: green;"
                                                        "font-weight: bold;"
                                                        "border-radius: 15px; /* Задайте радиус, чтобы сделать края овальными */\n"
                                                        "padding: 2px;")
                
                QTimer.singleShot(3000, self.clear_message)
                self.fname = ""

            except Exception as e:
                # Если произошло исключение, обработаем его и покажем сообщение об ошибке
                self.main_screen.lineEdit_3.setText("Ошибочный файл")
                self.main_screen.lineEdit_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(66, 71, 90);"
                                                        "color: red;"
                                                        "font-weight: bold;"
                                                        "border-radius: 15px; /* Задайте радиус, чтобы сделать края овальными */\n"
                                                        "padding: 2px;")
                QTimer.singleShot(3000, self.clear_message)
                self.show_error_message("Вы выбрали файл, содержащий не подходящую структуру. Пожалуйста выберите правильный файл!")
                
        else:
            self.main_screen.lineEdit_3.setText("Ошибка конвертации!")
            self.main_screen.lineEdit_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(66, 71, 90);"
                                                    "color: red;"
                                                    "font-weight: bold;"
                                                    "border-radius: 15px; /* Задайте радиус, чтобы сделать края овальными */\n"
                                                    "padding: 2px;")
            QTimer.singleShot(3000, self.clear_message)


            self.show_error_message("Пожалуйста выберите файл для конвертации!")
        

    info_about_file = -1
    #Работает
    def add_in_database(self):
        global info_about_file
        try:
            with open("configuration.yml", 'r') as file:
                config_data = yaml.safe_load(file)

            if "postgresql" in config_data:
                result = config_data["postgresql"]
                try:
                    self.add_file_json() #Тут происходит выбор файла, который надо загружать в базу
                    self.connectt(result['user'],
                            result['password'],
                            result['host'],
                            result['port'],
                            result['database'],
                            result['options'],
                            result['table'])
                    if info_about_file == 0:
                        self.main_screen.lineEdit_3.setText("Успешно!")
                        self.main_screen.lineEdit_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(66, 71, 90);"
                                                        "color: green;"
                                                        "font-weight: bold;"
                                                        "border-radius: 15px; /* Задайте радиус, чтобы сделать края овальными */\n"
                                                        "padding: 2px;")
                        QTimer.singleShot(3000, self.clear_message)
                        info_about_file = -1

                    if info_about_file == 1:
                        self.main_screen.lineEdit_3.setText("Json файл не найден!")
                        self.main_screen.lineEdit_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(66, 71, 90);"
                                                        "color: red;"
                                                        "font-weight: bold;"
                                                        "border-radius: 15px; /* Задайте радиус, чтобы сделать края овальными */\n"
                                                        "padding: 2px;")
                        QTimer.singleShot(3000, self.clear_message)
                        self.show_error_message("Json файл не найден. Пожалуйста проверьте наличие файла")
                        info_about_file = 0
                except Exception as e:
                    self.show_error_message("Проверьте правильность заполнения конфигурационного файла. Возможно, у вас нет доступа или в JSON файле присутствует ошибка.")        

            else:
                self.show_error_message(f"Секция 'postgresql' не найдена в конфигурационном файле.")
        except FileNotFoundError:
            self.show_error_message("Конфигурационный файл не найден. Пожалуйста убедитесь, что конфигурационный файл находится в одной папке с программой и называется: 'configuration.yml'")

     
    #Показать сообщение об ошибке
    def show_error_message(self, message):
        info = QMessageBox(self)
        info.setIcon(QMessageBox.Warning)  # Устанавливаем тип иконки внутри окна
        info.setWindowTitle("Ошибка")
        info.setText(message)
        info.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok)

        # Устанавливаем внешнюю иконку для окна
        if hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
        # PyInstaller creates a temp folder and stores the path in _MEIPASS
            base_path = getattr(sys, '_MEIPASS', os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
            icon_path = os.path.join(base_path, 'images', 'gnivc2.png')
        else:
        # When running locally
            icon_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'images', 'gnivc2.png')

    # Устанавливаем внешнюю иконку для окна
        info.setWindowIcon(QIcon(icon_path))

        # Устанавливаем стиль для изменения фона
        info.setStyleSheet("""
        QMessageBox { 
            background-color: rgb(17, 18, 21); 
        }
        QMessageBox QLabel {
            color: rgb(255, 255, 255);  /* Цвет текста */
        }
        QPushButton { 
            color: white; 
            background-color: rgb(151, 102, 255); 
        }
        """)

        info.exec_()


    #Очиска поля с информацией
    def clear_message(self):
        self.main_screen.lineEdit_3.setText("")
        self.main_screen.lineEdit_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(66, 71, 90);\n"
"color: rgb(162, 162, 162);\n"
"border-radius: 15px; /* Задайте радиус, чтобы сделать края овальными */\n"
"padding: 2px;")


    #Выгрузка данных в базу
    def connectt(self, user, password, host, port, database, options, table):
        global info_about_file
        try:
            # Подключение к существующей базе данных
            connection = psycopg2.connect(user=user, 
                                        password=password, 
                                        host=host, 
                                        port=port, 
                                        database=database,
                                        options=options)
            connection.autocommit = True

            # Курсор для выполнения операций с базой данных
            cursor = connection.cursor()
            
            # documents_folder = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), "Documents")
            # json_file_name = os.path.join(documents_folder, os.path.splitext(os.path.basename("pvd_deploy_template_koeiz"))[0] + ".json")
            # print(self.fname)
            try:
                with open(self.fname, 'r') as file:
                    content = file.read()
                    data = json.loads(content)
            except FileNotFoundError:
                info_about_file = 1
                print("Json файл не найден")
                return

            cursor.execute("""SET ROLE ais3;""")
            # cursor.execute("""SET SEARCH_PATH=demo;""")
            for item in data:
                server_name = item['hostname']
                server_role = item['data']
                cursor.execute(f"""INSERT INTO {table} (server_name, server_role) VALUES (%s, %s);""",
                    (server_name, json.dumps(server_role)))

            print("Всё хорошо")
            info_about_file = 0
        # except psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable:
        #     info_about_file = 1
        #     print("Ошибка: таблица не найдена")
        except (Exception, Error) as error:
            # info_about_file = 1
            print("Ошибка при работе с PostgreSQL", error)
        finally:
            if connection:
                cursor.close()
                connection.close()
                print("Соединение с PostgreSQL закрыто")
                self.fname = ""

#Функция конвертации
def SplitFileByDuplicates(file_name):
        def construct_yaml_map(self, node):
            data = []
            yield data
            for key_node, value_node in node.value:
                key = self.construct_object(key_node, deep=True)
                val = self.construct_object(value_node, deep=True)
                data.append((key, val))
        #try:
        with open(file_name, "r") as f:
                SafeConstructor.add_constructor(u'tag:yaml.org,2002:map', construct_yaml_map)
                yaml = YAML(typ='safe')
                data = yaml.load(f.read())
                result = []
                for i in data:
                    if i[0] == 'servers':
                        result.append(i)
                servers = result[0][1]
                
                def create_partition(server_list):
                    documents_folder = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), "Documents")
                    json_file_name = os.path.join(documents_folder, os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file_name))[0] + ".json")
                    
                    with open(json_file_name, "w") as f:
                        json.dump(server_list, f, indent=4)

                        

                server_list = []
                for server in servers:
                    server_name = server[0]
                    server_data = server[1]
                    server_entry = {
                        "hostname": server_name,
                        "data": {k: v for k, v in server_data}
                    }
                    server_list.append(server_entry)

                if server_list:
                    create_partition(server_list)


    

def application():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    application()

mainNew.py (QT файл):
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'mainNew.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.9
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(443, 592)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet("#centralwidget{background-color: rgb(17, 18, 21);}")
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(165, 38))
        self.widget.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 16777215))
        self.widget.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(17, 18, 21);")
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.widget)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(151, 102, 255);")
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.widget, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.widget_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(421, 104))
        self.widget_2.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 16777215))
        self.widget_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(23, 25, 33);")
        self.widget_2.setObjectName("widget_2")
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.widget_2)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName("verticalLayout_3")
        self.line = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.widget_2)
        self.line.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(151, 102, 255);")
        self.line.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line.setObjectName("line")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.line)
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout.addItem(spacerItem)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget_2)
        self.label_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(61, 60))
        self.label_2.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(61, 60))
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("background-image: url(:/file/images/yml3.png);")
        self.label_2.setText("")
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget_2)
        self.lineEdit_3.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(271, 31))
        self.lineEdit_3.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(291, 16777215))
        self.lineEdit_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(66, 71, 90);\n"
"color: rgb(162, 162, 162);\n"
"border-radius: 15px; /* Задайте радиус, чтобы сделать края овальными */\n"
"padding: 2px;")
        self.lineEdit_3.setCursorPosition(0)
        self.lineEdit_3.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_3)
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget_2)
        self.label_3.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(61, 60))
        self.label_3.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(61, 60))
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("background-image: url(:/file/images/json3.png);")
        self.label_3.setText("")
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label_3)
        spacerItem1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout.addItem(spacerItem1)
        self.verticalLayout_3.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
        self.line_2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.widget_2)
        self.line_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(151, 102, 255);")
        self.line_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line_2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line_2.setObjectName("line_2")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.line_2)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.widget_2)
        self.widget_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget_3.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 414))
        self.widget_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(17, 18, 21);")
        self.widget_3.setObjectName("widget_3")
        self.verticalLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.widget_3)
        self.verticalLayout_5.setObjectName("verticalLayout_5")
        self.verticalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_4.setContentsMargins(-1, 0, -1, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setSpacing(13)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setObjectName("verticalLayout_4")
        self.addFile = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widget_3)
        self.addFile.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(211, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.addFile.setFont(font)
        self.addFile.setStyleSheet("#addFile {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(151, 102, 255);\n"
"/*background-color: rgb(0, 139, 247);*/\n"
"    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 15px; /* Задайте радиус, чтобы сделать края овальными */\n"
"padding: 2px;}\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"#addFile:hover{\n"
"background-color: rgb(164, 205, 217);\n"
"}")
        self.addFile.setObjectName("addFile")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.addFile)
        self.convert = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widget_3)
        self.convert.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(211, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.convert.setFont(font)
        self.convert.setStyleSheet("#convert {\n"
"background-color: rgb(151, 102, 255);\n"
"/*background-color: rgb(0, 139, 247);*/\n"
"    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 15px; /* Задайте радиус, чтобы сделать края овальными */\n"
"padding: 2px;}\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"#convert:hover{\n"
"background-color: rgb(164, 205, 217);\n"
"}")
        self.convert.setObjectName("convert")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.convert)
        self.add = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widget_3)
        self.add.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(211, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.add.setFont(font)
        self.add.setStyleSheet("#add {\n"
"background-color: rgb(151, 102, 255);\n"
"/*background-color: rgb(0, 139, 247);*/\n"
"    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 15px; /* Задайте радиус, чтобы сделать края овальными */\n"
"padding: 2px;}\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"#add:hover{\n"
"background-color: rgb(164, 205, 217);\n"
"}")
        self.add.setObjectName("add")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.add)
        spacerItem2 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.verticalLayout_4.addItem(spacerItem2)
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget_3)
        self.label_4.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(200, 200))
        self.label_4.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(9999, 9999))
        self.label_4.setStyleSheet("background-image: url(:/file/images/gnvclogo.png);")
        self.label_4.setText("")
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.label_4, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        spacerItem3 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.verticalLayout_4.addItem(spacerItem3)
        self.info = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widget_3)
        self.info.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(211, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.info.setFont(font)
        self.info.setStyleSheet("#info {\n"
"background-color: rgb(151, 102, 255);\n"
"/*background-color: rgb(0, 139, 247);*/\n"
"    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 15px; /* Задайте радиус, чтобы сделать края овальными */\n"
"padding: 2px;}\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"#info:hover{\n"
"background-color: rgb(164, 205, 217);\n"
"}")
        self.info.setObjectName("info")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.info)
        self.verticalLayout_5.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_4)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.widget_3, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Конвертация YML в JSON"))
        self.lineEdit_3.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "Название файла.yml"))
        self.addFile.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выбрать файл"))
        self.convert.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Конвертировать"))
        self.add.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Добавить Json в Базу даных"))
        self.info.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Дополнительная информация"))
import qrc_files.file


Зачем весь свой проект сюда вываливать?! Можно же собрать минимальный пример на 20 строк и спросить почему не работает, как поправить... к чему 100500 строк кода, они к вопросу как относятся?!

@Amgarak Добрый день! Это не весь проект, а минимальная часть, чтобы его хоть как-то запустить. Негатив ни к чему :)

Не поймите превратна, ноль негатива. Но неужели для данного вопроса, действительно нужно столько кода?

@Amgarak Я предполагаю, что да. Необходимо просто создать в одной папке два пайтон файла.
main.py и mainNew.py Далее необходимо просто скопировать код. Далее создать файл main.spec и скопировать туда настройки. По другому проект не запустить

Метод nameProgramm у меня отрабатывает, иконка через setWindowIcon у меня устанавливается. Так что не очень понимаю к чему весь остальной код..

Никита Пфейфер, я не знаю как можно запустить ваш минимальный пример. 1. Добавьте скриншот  вашей НЕ скомпилированной программы и на нем покажите какие изображения/иконки у вас в дальнейшем отображаются, а какие нет. 2. Что такое  import qrc_files.file ? 3. Почему вы в одних местах  используете файл ресурсов :/file/images/yml3.png , а в других не используете его os.path.join(base_path, 'images', 'iconlogo3.png') ?

На сайте pyinstaller указаны опции использования. Если Вам нужно включить в проект дополнительные файлы, в .cmd должна быть одна относительно простая команда:
pyinstaller -y --uac-admin --clean ^
--onedir --runtime-tmpdir="." --distpath="." --contents-directory="Runtimes" ^
--add-data=".\ICONS\icon1.ico;ICONS" ^
--add-data=".\ICONS\icon2.ico;ICONS" ^
--hide-console=hide-early --icon=.\ICONS\app.png .\myproject.py

Взаимодействие с включёнными в автономную сборку дополнительными файлами - уже Ваша проблема.
Предлагаю самостоятельно сходить всё-таки на сайт и посмотреть о чём каждая из опций.
Кроме того, в проектах можно вообще не ссылаться на графические файлы. Их можно встраивать прямо в код скрипта. Это уменьшает количество потенциальных проблем. Пример:
images_app = tkinter.PhotoImage(data = base64.b64decode(r"iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAAgCAYAAABzenr0AAAAZElEQVR42u3TwQ2AQAhEUeiMUizNUugM7xoxm4ybNf65QuAdwM2sTBsfbS6VwAEA+AVgaPpbgNhDsjy3BLAgQH1kHfYekKLHDAcA4COAa2Uu4JwCAACAEvCUGYBWAWBRgDYt4AB1vYwN5931twAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="))
root.iconphoto(True, images_app)

